# common HTML parts of webpages

Tags: html, asp.net

I’m designing a website with asp.net.

In my website I have many web pages.

All pages have a same header, and same menu, and same right menu bar, and others.

Note that the main data in each page is different from others.

For this, I copy the common HTML part of each page and paste it in new page!

Common parts like these:

```
div id=”headerDIV” style=… >
…
/div>
```

My problem is that how can I type these common parts of each page just one time and use it in all pages?

Without doing like this, I should change all pages when I wanna change a little thing in the header for example!

I think one way is to save the common HTML part in one .html file, and use it like this:

```
<!--#include file="header.html"-->
```

But, is it a best solution ?!

Isn’t it cause bad loading of the website especially for users with low speed Internet !?

Is there any better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a decent walk through about master pages: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333650/Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-Master-Pages-in-ASP-NET

Comment: you sure you did your homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using razor you should learn how to use [layout pages](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx) these pages contain the shared components that you are talking about. If you are not using razor then use [master pages](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/creating-a-site-wide-layout-using-master-pages-cs).

Razor is the latest view engine in ASP.NET so modern application will be more likely to use Razor and MVC, legacy software will be more likely to use Web Forms and Master Pages.

Answer (score 2):

What your asking to achieve is simply implemented using a [master page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Both ASP.NET WebForms as well as MVC support master pages in their own flavor.  Master pages let you implement a common layout while including content sections to display individual page content.